# Minimum Hop Count in Directed Graph based on Conditional Statement

Tags: graph-theory, fastest-algorithm

A directed graph **G** is given with Vertices **V** and Edges **E**, representing train stations and unidirectional train routes respectively.

Trains of different train numbers move in between pairs of Vertices in a single direction.

Vertices of **G** are connected with one another through trains with allotted train numbers.

A hop is defined when a passenger needs to shift trains while moving through the graph. The passenger needs to shift trains only if the train-number changes.

Given two Vertices **V1** and **V2**, how would one go about calculating the minimum number of hops needed to reach **V2** starting from **V1**?

---

[image: graph]

In the above example, the minimum number of hops between Vertices **0** and **3** is 1.

There are two paths from 0 to 3, these are

`0 -> 1 -> 2 -> 7-> 3`

`Hop Count 4`

Hop Count is 4 as the passenger has to shift from Train A to B then C and B again.

and

`0 -> 5 -> 6 -> 8 -> 7 -> 3`

`Hop Count 1`

Hop Count is 1 as the passenger needs only one train route, B to get from Vertices **0** to **3**

Thus the minimum hop count is 1.

---

**Input Examples**

Input Graph Creation

[image]

Input To be solved

[image]

---

**Output Example**

Output - Solved with Hop Counts

[image]

0 in the `Hop Count` column implies that the destination can't be reached

Comment: Hi, and welcome to the site! Questions here should be in the form of challenges with a winning criterion, such as code-golf. Could you add such a criterion, and also add an example input, such as one matching the picture? Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I've edited the challenge to make the winning criteria based on algorithmic efficiency. I will shorty upload an example input. Thanks again!

Comment: You also [posted the same question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60769023) on StackOverflow. Are you looking for programming help?

Comment: @xnor, this is a question that I failed to answer, when my friend asked me. I told him that I would ask the StackExchange community. If I have violated any rules, I apologize, and I am ready to remove it from the SO or CG community.

Comment: How large can `V`, `E` and the number of trains be?

Comment: I took the liberty to edit the picture to add the missing train IDs. But feel free to rollback or edit further if necessary.

Comment: @mypronounismonicareinstate, the maximum values of `V`, `E`, and the number of trains are 5000, 10000, and 10 respectively.

Comment: Are we only meant to handle this graph, i.e. the input is just the two nodes? Or are given the graph as well?